# How do you actually load a test case into Kiwi TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

how do i run my python code, and parameterize (5 min / 10 min / 15 min) in kiwi? i can not find this specific instruction in the user manual.

could i use kiwi to manage OS images for pxe boot servers?